# Individual unit tests for each output of a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, xunit, xunit.net

I have a method that takes a file as input and then returns N outputs based on this file.

I want to test this method in the following way: Say we have M files to test. For each file, I want to add one line to the test program (or to a separate file), consisting of the file path and the N expected outputs. This data should give rise to N*M individual tests, one for each pair of file and expected output.

Is there a good way to achieve this? I want each file to be parsed no more than once for each test run.

Below is an example that does what I want. As you can see, I have to add individual test classes for each file. I hope to find a solution where I can add just the line with the test data (e.g. `testData.Add(("thirdfile", 4), (348, 312));`) to test a new file.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

    public static class FileParser
    {
        private static int n = 0;

        public static void Init(int parameter)
        {
            n = parameter;
        }

        public static (int output1, int output2) ParseFile(string filename)
        {
            return (filename[0] * n, filename[1] * n);
        }
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        private Dictionary<(string, int), (int, int)> testData;

        public Tests()
        {
            testData = new Dictionary<(string, int), (int, int)>();
            testData.Add(("somefile", 3), (345, 333));
            testData.Add(("anotherfile", 4), (291, 330));
            testData.Add(("thirdfile", 4), (348, 312));
        }

        public void TestOutput1((int, int) result, string filename, int parameter)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(testData[(filename, parameter)].Item1, result.Item1);
        }

        public void TestOutput2((int, int) result, string filename, int parameter)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(testData[(filename, parameter)].Item2, result.Item2);
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Somefile
    {
        protected static (int, int) fileParseResult;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
        {
            FileParser.Init(3);
            fileParseResult = FileParser.ParseFile("somefile");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SomefileOutput1() { var tests = new Tests(); tests.TestOutput1(fileParseResult, "somefile", 3); }
        [TestMethod]
        public void SomefileOutput2() { var tests = new Tests(); tests.TestOutput2(fileParseResult, "somefile", 3); }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Anotherfile
    {
        protected static (int, int) fileParseResult;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
        {
            FileParser.Init(3);
            fileParseResult = FileParser.ParseFile("anotherfile");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AnotherfileOutput1() { var tests = new Tests(); tests.TestOutput1(fileParseResult, "anotherfile", 4); }
        [TestMethod]
        public void AnotherfileOutput2() { var tests = new Tests(); tests.TestOutput2(fileParseResult, "anotherfile", 4); }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Thirdfile
    {
        protected static (int, int) fileParseResult;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
        {
            FileParser.Init(3);
            fileParseResult = FileParser.ParseFile("thirdfile");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ThirdfileOutput1() { var tests = new Tests(); tests.TestOutput1(fileParseResult, "thirdfile", 4); }
        [TestMethod]
        public void ThirdfileOutput2() { var tests = new Tests(); tests.TestOutput2(fileParseResult, "thirdfile", 4); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged `xunit.net` but isn't `[TestMethod]` from _Microsoft's_ testing framework? I think xUnit has `[Fact]` attributes? - The specific testing framework is probably crucially important to what implementations are possible.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, that's right. I hoped to be able to use xUnit, but I am open for both.

Comment: "A test is not a unit test if it touches the file system" https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923
You could however easily mock the file system with https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions

Comment: Why don't you generate the unit test code with T4 templates? All the file probing and parsing magic would be in the generator, the unit tests end up clean and simple.

Comment: @dfhwze I hadn't heard about it. I will look into it.

Answer (score 6):

You may actually be able to simplify this so that new tests on that library wouldn't necessarily require a code change to the test library itself.

MS documentation for data driven unit tests can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2019).

I have seen people use something like that with a csv file, then when a new test is needed, they simply add a row to the csv file.

Alternatively, I'd personally like the DataRow feature available in MSTest.
Example MS Doc can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.3.2). I prefer this option, though a new test case does require a new line of code.

It should reduce the amount of code overall. Something a bit like this.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class FileClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow("somefile", 3, 345, 333)]
    [DataRow("anotherfile", 4, 291, 330)]
    public void Output1IsValid(string fileName, int parameter, int resultX, int resultY) 
    { 
        var fileParseResult = FileParser.ParseFile(fileName);
        Assert.AreEqual(fileParseResult.Item1, resultX);         
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. There is an important requirement, though, which I did not specify: Each file should only be parsed once, not once per test. Sorry about this.

Comment: @Aae unit tests should be executed over and over by definition as the code base changes, why can't you parse all of your files once. You don't need tests for that

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo I am not sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate? The ParseFile method is subject to change.

Comment: sorry, it was late night when I was posting this  statement, did not understand your original question. I see now that what you want is class initialize parameters, but I dont think there is something like this. I guess your code is only common way to achieve this

Comment: @Aae however, you can still use inheritance in test classes, e.g. your base test will have Output1 and Output2 methods and constructor with file name string.

Comment: @Aae can you not combine this answer's essence (using DataRowAttribute) with the approach in your question and use [ClassInitialize]?

Comment: @sa.he I guess I will have to repeat the DataRow lines for each output? So it doesn't really quite work.

Comment: @Aae, you are right. Every line of [DataRow] results in a separat unit test in your test window. xUnit has the same idea but calls it [Theory] and [InlineData]. AFAIK this is the closest you can get.

Comment: @sa.he Wouldn't an external file solve that? But to combine this approach with mine, do I have to store the results of all file parsings? I cannot parsed one file at a time? That will be a problem if I want to run just a few of the tests.

Comment: @Aae Using an external configuration file for your test is unusual but possible. But does not lead to individual tests in the test window (which I understood to be the main reason of your question).

Answer (score 2):

In case you're open to more than MSTest or xUnit, you can checkout [Nuclear.Test](https://mikelimasierra.net/index.php/software-projects/nuclear-test-platform/).

Create a data driven test method that takes care of parsing *and* checking both result items at once.

```cs
[TestMethod]
[TestParamters("someFile", 3, (345, 333))]
[TestParamters("anotherfile", 4, (291, 330))]
[TestParamters("thirdfile", 4, (348, 312))]
void TestFile(String someFile, Int32 parameter, (Int32, Int32) expected) {

    (Int32, Int32) result = null;
    
    Test.Note("Parsing '" + someFile + "'");
    Test.IfNot.Action.ThrowsException(() => FileParser.Init(parameter), out Exception ex);
    Test.IfNot.Action.ThrowsException(() => result = FileParser.ParseFile(someFile), out ex);
    Test.IfNot.Object.IsNull(result);
    
    Test.Note("Checking results for '" + someFile + "'");
    Test.If.Value.IsEqual(result.Item1, expected.Item1);
    Test.If.Value.IsEqual(result.Item2, expected.Item2);
    
}
```

More information on writing data driven tests with Nuclear.Test can be found [here](https://mikelimasierra.net/index.php/software-projects/nuclear-test-platform/guide-extending-the-framework/).

Please note that this requires at least .NETStandard 2.0 at the moment.
I do realize that you may not be open to a different unit testing platform, however since you did say you're open to either MSTest or xUnit i guess you haven't quite decided yet.

This approach also works with MSTest and xUnit, however this would break [OAPT](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2014/06/17/one-assertion-per-test/) in these scenarios whereas Nuclear.Test is immune to those restrictions.

Please note that i wasn't able to test this code since i'm writing from my phone. There may be typos or a bug in there.

**UPDATE:**

this will be a legit approach using MSTest:

```cs
[TestMethod]
[DataRow("someFile", 3, (345, 333))]
[DataRow("anotherfile", 4, (291, 330))]
[DataRow("thirdfile", 4, (348, 312))]
public void TestFileParser(String fileName, Int32 parameter, (Int32, Int32) expected) {

    FileParser.Init(parameter);
    var result = FileParser.ParseFile(fileName);
    Assert.AreEqual(result, expected);

}
```

Turns out ValueTuple implements IComparable<(T1, T2)> and can be compared in one assert.

Comment: This looks interesting. I need one test per output, if that's what you mean I don't get with this approach under MSTest or xUnit. I think, however, that the lack of Visual Studio integration prevents me from going with Nuclear.Test.

Comment: if you don't care much about oapt (which i think in this case may be alright to ignore) then just go with this approach using xunit. It will give you the same flexibility of having one line of code per test case added while not being such a pain to implement. it'll be 3 asserts and you'll only have to parse each file once.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a way to make this possible with less code, following @pwrigshihanomoronimos approach. But then you will most likely need unit tests to make sure, the tests are working properly, so I would advice against it.

I know, writing such tests can be very tedious, but with unit tests there is one rule above all.

> **Keep them as simple as possibly possible.**

Just use the bare minimum of complexity, which is absolutely necessary to make the test possible at all.

> The less complex, the less error prone.

Better to have a separate file, with all the parameters and outputs to compare against and to read it up front.

Comment: If the tests can be written once and for all, I don't have a problem with having to check that they are working properly. The important part here is to be able to add new test data with as little work as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Andreas to keep a unit test simple. Therefore reading a configuration file (a file that configures what the unit test does) would not be advisable. The following sample code extends @James Pusateri good answer by ensuring that evey file is read just once.

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        // Use a static Lazy<T> instance to read your file just once. 
        // Replace <object> with your type. 
        // Use multiple of these Lazy variables by using a Dictionary<string, Lazy<YourResultType>>
        private static Lazy<object> fileParseResult = new Lazy<object>(() => FileParser.ParseFile("somefile"));

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanup()
        {
            // in case you need to clean up something, do it here
            // fileParseResult.Value.Dispose() if applicable
            fileParseResult = null;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [DataRow("somefile", 3, 345, 333)]
        [DataRow("anotherfile", 4, 291, 330)]
        // add additional DataRow-lines here as required
        public void OutputIsValid(string fileName, int parameter, int resultX, int resultY)
        {
            // make sure to only read 'fileParseResult.Value' and not change it.
            Assert.AreEqual(fileParseResult.Value, fileName);
        }

        // dummy implementation for testing this code. Use your implemenation instead.
        private class FileParser
        {
            internal static object ParseFile(string v) => v;
        }
    }
```

**MSTest** This is a nice cheat-sheet https://www.automatetheplanet.com/mstest-cheat-sheet/

**xUnit** has a similar approach but uses different attributes `[Theory]` and `[InlineData]`. Also xUnit has more sophisticated (and complex) possibilities of context sharing https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context. Up to now, I've always managed to simplify the test scenarios in a way that these advanced context sharing features were not required.

**Experience and personal opinion** Actually, I do not use any context sharing for unit tests. The reason is refactoring. Consider the need to add another test method which requires a slightly different shared context. So you'd go ahead and change the shared context and unintendenly break a number of existing tests. Also I avoid reading any files inside unit tests, but rather use mocks that return a predefined and predictable result.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a better look at this as soon as I have access to Visual Studio. I have two questions, though. Where is `anotherfile` parsed in this code? And when you say that reading a configuration file is not an option, do you mean that it is not advisable to [read the test data from a CSV file](https://github.com/ObjectivityLtd/Ocaramba/wiki/MsTest-DataDriven-tests-from-Xml-and-CSV-files)?

Comment: A configuration file is possible but not advisable IMHO. 'anotherfile' can be added by duplicating the Lazy<T> variable or using a List or Dictionary.

Comment: The goal here is to be able to add new tests by adding just one line with test data to the code or, maybe preferably, to an external file. Is that achievable with this approach?

Comment: Sorry, I'm repeating myself. A new code line of `[DataRow("some-third-file", 1, 2, 3)]` adds a new test. IMHO unit tests should be a matter of coding, not a matter of configuration. When coding you have compiler checks, IntelliSense refactoring tools etc. When writing a configuration file you have none of this.

Answer (score 0):

Using xUnit and System Linq

Using InlineData (*or MemberData if you want it separate*) containing both of your test results covers your requirement for adding one line of data to run multiple checks, however I'm not sure that

> Each file should only be parsed once, not once per test.

is possible without some way of recording what files you've parsed in previous test runs, and plugging that in to the **if()** statement

```
public class ExampleTest
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData ("somefile", 3, 332, 354)]
    [InlineData ("anotherfile", 3, 290, 337)]
    [InlineData ("thirdfile", 4, 310, 304)]
    public void FileParseOutputIsCorrect ( string fileName, int parameter, int resultA, int resultB )
    {
        //conditional check only necessary if you want to stop parsing in future test runs
        if ( !fileName.Parsed )
        {
            var fileParseResult = FileParser.ParseFile ( fileName, parameter );
            Assert.Equal ( fileParseResult[0], resultA );
            Assert.Equal ( fileParseResult[1], resultB );
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( $"Already parsed {fileName}" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your Output1 and Output2 methods are quite similar, you can use inheritance approach. Then you can apply test parameter insertion, if required

```
public class BaseTest
{
    private readonly string fileName;

    public BaseTest(string fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // do your work with fileName
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void TestOutput1()
    {
        // test body
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void TestOutput2()
    {
        // test body
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestFile1 : BaseTest
{
    public TestFile1() : base("file1")
    {
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestFile2 : BaseTest
{
    public TestFile2() : base("file2")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this still requires writing individual test classes for each file, so it doesn't really take me to the goal.